# Context Aware modification - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function

in a pandas dataframe, I have a column that contains condition like the following examples:

- "(XCondition)"
- "(XCondition AND YCondition)"
- "(XCondition) AND (YCondition)"
- "((XCondition) AND (YCondition)) OR (ZCondition)"

Now imagine I want to delete the XCondition.
As you can see there are multiple context possible for XCondition:

- with or without parenthesis
- with a following keyword or not
- inside a sublogic or not

Just deleting the string "XCondition" will not give me a working file.

My current approach is to build a quite complex function and then use the df.apply() method to deal with it.

I know this is quite a complex problem that requires quite a complex function but I am wondering if anything really exist to solve this nicely.

If anyone has experience on this kind of problem and have some tips for it.
I will be glad to hear it.

Comment: Can you add some data sample? What is `XCondition, YCondition, ZCondition` in sample data ?

Comment: Good point. 
It is just a string. It is usually a single word - no space. It represent a meta attributes.
You could replace by city if your prefer (city without space):
- "(Paris)"
- "(Paris AND Chicago)"
- "(Paris) AND (Chicago)"
- "((Paris) AND (Chicago)) OR (London)"

Comment: With logic if you want to replace a condition just set it to True all the time.